# mouse not working

Tags: mouse

Upon starting ubuntu my mouse works perfectly, but after a few seconds I can no longer click or select using the mouse. After these few seconds, the pointer itself still moves on the screen fine. However, when I move the pointer over something that should be highlighted when the mouse is over it, it does not highlight nor can I click to open it. I am running Ubuntu 12.04.3 lts on my PC if that helps. I have tried using an external mouse but the same issue occurs.